# How to use IFS to create multiple arrays from a text file?

Tags: shell-script, array

Suppose I have a text file `filename.txt`

```
cat filename.txt
abc#123
def#456
```

Now I want to use IFS in such a way that two arrays are created such as:

```
source=(abc def)
dest=(123 456)
```

What would be the logic to create the two separate arrays?

Answer (score 7):

You can re-direct your input file to a `while`/`read` loop and set the `IFS` value to `#` to split the line contents. Should work on any `bash`/`ksh` or `zsh` shell.

```
while IFS=# read -r s d; do
    source+=( "$s" )        
      dest+=( "$d" )
done < filename.txt
```